# Is PicoPSU hazardous?

Tags: power-supply

If I use a [PicoPSU](http://www.mini-box.com/DC-DC), the computer is connected to an external 12V adapter (power brick) by a simple two pole +/- connector. The protective earth is not connected to the PC.

Does this situation involve any life-threatening risk in case of electric failure?

(Normally the computers are powered with standard ATX power supplies, which are connected to the power system by a three wire cable. One of the wires is the protective earth (PE) which is connected to all exposed metallic parts of the computer (case, backplate, audio jacks, etc.)

Comment: Regardless of whether this is a safety issue I am sceptical that the PicoPSU can put out 150W without melting.

Comment: That's not an issue for me, because the whole box consumes about 40 watts :)

Comment: @ThomasO afaict they kinda cheat. If you read the manual, the 12V rail is only switched, it doesn't go through any voltage conversion. So they only have to provide voltage conversion for the 5V, 3.3V, 5VSB and -12V rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rationale behind grounding the cases of mains powered equipment has to do with the fact that one side (the 'neutral') of the AC mains is typically already tied to ground, by the utility company. If a piece of equipment had an un-grounded case, and a physical failure inside the unit caused the other leg of the mains (the 'hot' side) to contact the exposed surface, a potentially lethal hazard would be created; anyone coming into contact with the case and a ground at the same time would be directly across the full mains voltage.

Now consider running from a 12V supply. Some low voltage DC supplies do tie one side of their output to ground, some don't, it depends on the supply. Obviously if one side is grounded, the same possibility exists that an internal failure could energize the case with respect to ground, albeit at only 12V. If you have the output-not-grounded kind, even if the case comes into contact with one of the 12V supply leads, and you touch that case, you aren't likely to come into contact with the other side of the 12V supply, unless you really work at it.

Personally, I wouldn't worry too much about the lack of an earth-ground in a 12V system. The odds of a multi-point failure that would result in getting one's person across the 12V supply are low, and even if it happens, it's only 12V. But a parting word about 'only 12V' - if your skin is dry, and you apply 12V to it, chances are you won't even feel it, but if you have significant moisture on your skin, especially salty moisture, you definitely can feel it. I wouldn't recommend the experience. Also, even though the voltage is low, you can often get enough current from low voltage supplies to turn rings, metal watch straps, etc. red hot, also un-fun.

Answer (score 1):

If the adapter has been designed properly it should meet all the relevant safety standards and no ground connection needs to be made.

I use [Stontronics](http://www.stontronics.co.uk/) mains adapters. They are UL/CUL and GS approved.

Comment: The double insulation does not have to concern to the whole device? For example if the adapter goes wrong and outputs 230V, the metal parts of the PC became lethal isn't it?

Comment: If it outputs 230V something in the PC will probably explode! Those regulations prevent anything like that happening.

Answer (score 0):

The picoPSUs input voltage is 12V and the highest output voltage difference is 24V (between the +12V and -12V rails). As far as I can tell the PicoPSUs do not provide any form of isolation barrier. 24V is not generally considered to present a significant electric shock hazard (high current 12V systems can be a fire/burn hazard though).

So the question of whether or not the system is safe from electric shock does not really have anything to do with the PicoPSU. Instead it comes down to the power brick.

There are various approaches a power brick vendor can take, they can design the power brick with "class 2" insulation between input and output, or they can use mains ground as a barrier between input and output. If they are using mains ground as a barrier between input and output they may or may not connect the output ground to mains ground.

Either way, the power brick is the safety device that acts as a barrier between you and the mains, you should buy power bricks from a reputable vendor and if the power brick has a ground connection you should ensure it is actually connected to ground.

Power bricks sold in the EU should have at least a CE mark and the details of the manufacturer/importer who are legally responsible for ensuring that they are safe. AIUI in the US there is an expectation that products will be tested by a "nationally recognised testing lab" such as UL, though I'm not sure if it's actually a legal requirement.